# Fatal error log in customers in prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop-1.6

Since a couple of days, we started to experience some issues when a new client wanted to log in. It appears a fatal error with an entirely white screen. 
We detected that it happens when the customer signed up but they didn't introduce the address. It happens when they try to log in again.

I would really appreciate if someone had this problem and know how to fix it.

Many thanks in advance

David

Comment: post the error message from error_log. also, did you change the account creation to require the address?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was related to MailChimp Integration v1.0.0 module. My customer installed that module and did not complete the configuration.
After disabling MailChimp module, Prestashop log in has resumed working properly.